# I can't get d3-maps to draw my "Landkreise"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I got geodata from the "Bundesamt für Kartographie" (Federal Agency for Cartography) from which I extracted my geodata as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "SN_L = '16'" kreiseTh.json vg250_ebenen/VG250_KRS.shp
topojson -o kreiseTh.topo.json --id-property RS --properties name=GEN -- kreiseTh.json
```

and put all that together (http://bl.ocks.org/HoffmannP/f8d07cf02b5687668116) but it just shows garbage.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1):

[topoJSON on D3: map doesn't show (but it works on www.mapshaper.org)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762358/topojson-on-d3-map-doesnt-show-but-it-works-on-www-mapshaper-org?rq=1) already had the details:

the data is already projected so what you have to do is unproject it by adding

```
-t_srs EPSG:4326
```

to your ogr2ogr call